# Question on rfcv - Random Forest Cross validaton

Tags: r, cross-validation, random-forest

The following code is part of randomForest "R" package documentation for rfcv.

```
myiris <- cbind(iris[1:4], matrix(runif(96 * nrow(iris)), nrow(iris), 96))
result <- rfcv(myiris, iris$Species, cv.fold=3)
```

**Questions:**
Why 96? Why inflate the input test data set (testX)? Is it ok to generate test data as shown above for cross validation?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is a bootstrap with $B=96$ bootstrap samples. Using these bootstrap samples, cross validation is performed. Boot strapped standard error bands match closely with estimated error bands.